# Flex layout in Boostrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I was trying to do a column layout that places each cell to the right of the other until it reachs the container width. Then, other following divs should continue rendering on the next line, and so on.

All examples I have seen so far, do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Al examples uses a container whose class is "row", however, I don't need that, because I don't know before hand how many columns could fit in the container width.

Is there a way to make columns to be ordered automatically to the right.

for example, something like:

```
<div style="float: left">...</div>
<div style="float: left">...</div>
<div style="float: left">...</div>
<div style="float: left">...</div>
```

But using Boostrap 4. Each div contains form_groups with a label and an input field.

Comment: on your `row` div, add a class `justify-content-end` or `flex-row-reverse`; if I'm understanding right, that should help you, let me know!

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Specifically, *"examples uses a container whose class is "row", however, I don't need that, because I don't know before hand how many columns could fit in the container width"* doesn't make sense.

Comment: That way I need to know how many elements fit in a row before hand. I have added a div with "d-flex" class, and all elements are placed in a row, adding a horizontal scroll to see all other elements. If the container grid allows only 2 elements, I need to show those 2 elements and the other to the next row, and so on

Comment: @jstuardo take a look at this https://codepen.io/IvanS95/pen/gQjOvN

Comment: Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/desytec/aq9Laaew/279455/. I need that "Bye" to appear to the right of "Hello", and so on.

Comment: Again, you should add a `row` and set `justify-content-end`, I just did it on you fiddle and worked fine

Comment: If for whatever reason you don't want to have a `row` class, then yes, just add a `d-flex` div and apply the same classes

Comment: I just read your comment, if you are getting an scroll you should add `flex-wrap` to the `d-flex` div

Comment: You can put as many columns as you want in the `row` and they will wrap to the next line as needed

Comment: @IvanS95 Thanks.... that code worked.... I have added 2 container divs, one with "container-fluid" class and the inner with "row justify-content-end" classes.... and inside it, I added elements with "<div class="p-10 border-bottom col-6">" and they were rendered as I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired output by adding a few classes to the basic `row` and `col-*-*` structure; to align every column to the right you can just add a `justify-content-end` class to the `row`, since rows have a `display: flex` property, you can apply all flex behaviors to rows; with this if there's space available, columns will be pushed to the right side;

Also if you would like to reverse the order of the columns, you can also add a class `flex-row-reverse` which, as the name implies, will render the columns in reverse order inside the row.

Working example
https://codepen.io/IvanS95/pen/gQjOvN